# How does one prove that elements of the Borel set are regular?

Tags: measure-theory

How does one prove that elements of the Borel set are regular?

A Borel set of course being any element of the Borel sigma algebra (say A), and regular meaning that for a given real number e, there is a compact set (C), contained in A, contained in an open set (O) for which m(O\C)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that the regular sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, and that compact sets are regular.